# Escaping & in filename for PHP download

Tags: php, html, escaping, download

Downloading file issues where the filename has & in it.

For example, a file called bla will download fine but bla & Blaaaaa doesn't locate the file.

Is there a way for me to escape the `&?`  I can't rename the files on the server, that would be easier but not possible.

The files are stored in the DB, then retrieved and trimmed of their unique appendage.  :)

```
$fileName = $eachFile['filename'];
$fileNamePretty = explode('__', $fileName); // ONLY FILENAME
```

and then in the download link I have:

```
        <a href="../download.php?filename=<?php echo $fileName?>">
```

and the download.php

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$dir = "training/trainingDocuments/";
$downloadFilename = $dir.$filename;

//8 - SUBSEA QUESTIONS__51f034ab37a8e.xls
//if the filename exists
if(is_file($downloadFilename)){

//send the headers
header('Pragma: public'); //FIX IE6 Content-Disposition
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Transder-Encoding: binary');
header(sprintf('Content-Length: %u', filesize($downloadFilename)));
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$downloadFilename."");

readfile($downloadFilename);

$training->addToDownload($filename);//updates download count

}else{
//file doesn't exist
echo "File no exist\n\n";
echo $downloadFilename;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: have you tried to escape the & in the uri by url encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If memory serves me right, & is escaped by being substituted with %26 by any url encoding function. Try using this:

```
<a href="../download.php?filename=<?php echo urlencode($fileName); ?>">
```

Otherwise everything after '&' is considered as a 2nd argument in the get method.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks you.  marked yours as the answer due to the useful %26.  I've used %20 to avoid w3c error for an empty action tag I think so will be useful.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function supplied by PHP:

```
urlencode($url);
```